# Automated extraction of domain name regristrant from WHOIS query responses

Tags: parsing, scripting, text-processing, whois

I am looking to develop a system that will retrieve the name (and optimally the e-mail address) of the registrant of a domain name from a WHOIS response. Writing a WHOIS parser by hand from scratch seems like a Herculean effort, as the format of WHOIS responses seems to differ for each TLD. I have also looked at the [Ruby-Whois](http://www.ruby-whois.org) gem for Ruby, and while I applaud the effort, it is just not extensive enough (cannot sucessfully parse a lot of WHOIS responses). Are there any other tools that anyone can point me towards that could help me in my task? I set out initially to code this in Ruby, the scripting language I feel most comfortable in, but if there are better tools available in Python or Perl (which I'm told is very well suitable to text processing/parsing) then I'm fully comfortable picking up those languages as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tool you are looking for is called [MultiLook](http://client.multilook.net/).

Comment: Wow thanks! A pretty decent programmer as well as a wheelchair-bound physics nerd, is there anything you can't do? This is for a summer internship, I'm hardly doing it for the craic ;)

Comment: That's Windows only unfortunately, was looking for a Linux based solution.